# How do I fix a non-signed commit error that made it onto the pipelines

Tags: git

I get an error in the GitHistoryChecker stage of GoCI's build pipeline with the following error:

```
05:48:41.029 FAILURE: [git commit hash] has not been signed with a valid signature
05:48:41.029 
05:48:41.030   Date:        2018-11-15 13:49:12 +0000
05:48:41.030   Author:      Stefan Brink <stefan@jemstep.com>
05:48:41.030   Committer:   Stefan Brink <stefan@jemstep.com>
05:48:41.030   Commit Date: 2018-11-15 13:49:12 +0000
05:48:41.030   SHA:         [SHA here]
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean GoCD? You should elaborate more on how the workflow normally works and what you do to sign it normally. I suppose that the remedy is buried in the documentation anyway.

Comment: I think https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits may contain the answer. The bad news is you have to rewrite the commit (and then all commits descending from that, I suppose), and then force-push to other repos which contain the unsigned commit.